# Does 240v appliances have higher resistance than 120v appliances?

Tags: current, resistance

Does 240v appliances have higher resistance than 120v appliances?

Assuming, the appliances consume the same amount of wattage.

Comment: Does R=V/I mean anything to you if P=constant?

Comment: What about an appliance that works on anything from 100 to 240V... like my laptop PSU?

Comment: -1 for not even the most basic research performed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do power is given as P=V^2/R this means that R=V^2/P. So for the same power if you double the voltage you need to increase the resistance by a factor of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use an electric water cooker for an example. We assume a power of 1200 W. At 120 V AC, the current is 10 A and the resistance 12 Ohm. At 240 V, the current is 5 A and the resistance 48 Ohm. This is true for all pure resistive appliances.